# What is mean of "data:lable.isLast== true(or false)" in blogger.com

Tags: blogger, blogspot

In the blogger.com code lines, I see `data: lable.isLast == true`. What does it mean?
Thank you!

P/s: Here are some Google docs, https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en#labels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete explanation:

Example code:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'><!-- this only for last label -->
<a class='category' expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:label.name' rel='category tag'><data:label.name/></a>
</b:if>
<!-- OR -->
<b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "false"'><!-- this is list of labels except last label -->
<a class='category' expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:label.name' rel='category tag'><data:label.name/></a>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:if>
```

---

`cond='data:post.labels'` mean is if the post have a label. Code inside this `b:if` (if condition) will exucate.

`b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'` mean loop all labal value inside this `b:loop`

inside `b:loop` conditional tag. `cond='data:label.isLast == "true"` is a condition codes, mean if it's a last label. it will apply only for last label. (actually if post only have 1 label, it can be data:label.isLast and data:label.isFirst (both) or `<b:else/>` of this `b:if` condition.

`cond='data:label.isLast == "false"` will apply for all labels except last label.

---

Here is another example. Maybe more easy to understand it with code, you can try it

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>

<b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
<a class='category' expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:label.name' rel='category tag'><data:label.name/></a> is last Label of this post.
</b:if>

<!-- OR -->
<b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "false"'>
<a class='category' expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:label.name' rel='category tag'><data:label.name/></a> is not last label of this post,
</b:if>

</b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Blogger, each post can have list of labels. you can use this expression `data:lable.isLast == true` as condition with [b:if tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969) to check if this label is the last one in the list and therefore display certain content or do other changes.
also you can only use `data:label.isLast` it can be true or false.

The next example allows you to print out each label name in the post and shows asterisk after the last label.

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <data:label.name/>
    <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == true'>*</b:if>
</b:loop>
```

Let's say we have three labels in the post the result would be : `label1` `label2` `label3*`

**Update :**

According to your next question you need to hide "zlabel" so `<b:if cond='data:label.isLast ==' true'>` there ensures that all post labels is going to be rendered before executing `<b:include/>` also, because b:include variable `var='...'` works with the first loop (*blog posts*) you can't repeat b:include with post labels loop.

Comment: Thank @bassam , i have new question, if you can